# Need to xml from a text container loaded text

Tags: actionscript-3

Need to xml from a text container loaded text. 
The problem is that different paragraphs of this test have a different format, such as some other fatty italics. 
Is it possible to do it in one container? 
If not then how to do it more than one container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self-contained example:

```
var txtField:TextField = new TextField(); 
txtField.width = 550; 
txtField.htmlText = "regular, <b>strong</b>,<i> italics </i>,<font size='24'>big</font>,<font     color='#FF0000'>red</font>"; 
addChild(txtField);
```

For larger information see HELP: flash.text.TextField method htmlText 
You can also use the CSS: flash.text.StyleSheet
http://help.adobe.com/ru_RU/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#htmlText